# Recursive XmlSerializer losing elements

Tags: xmlserializer

With C# and .Net 4.0, I have a recursive XSD schema. XML based on that XSD serializes just fine with XmlSerializer. It also deserializes with no errors, but without retrieving all of the elements.

Here's a snippit from the XSD:

```
  <xs:complexType name="SettingGroup">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Notes" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="SettingGroup" type="SettingGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <xs:element name="Setting" type="Setting" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Note that the type SettingGroup recursively contains 0 or more SettingGroup elements, and also 0 or more elements of a different type named Setting. It works well when a SettingGroup contains just SettingGroups or when it contains just Settings. But, when the SettingGroup has both SettingGroups and Settings, although it serializes as expected, when deserialized, all of the Settings elements are missing.

I have also tried using ref, with similar results:

```
<xs:element ref="SettingGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
```

I created the .xsd file by hand, and used xsd.exe to create the C# classes.

In case it may be of use, here's the definition of Setting:

```
  <xs:complexType name="Setting">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Notes" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="Roam" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" default="true" />
      <!--<xs:element name="RoamConditions" type="RoamConditions" />-->
      <xs:element name="SettingLocation" type="SettingLocation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions about why deserialization can't retrieve all elements.